# Seeing the logs of requests sent to Telegram Bot API

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I've set up a Telegram bot. All queries to the Telegram Bot API must be served over HTTPS and are presented in this form: https://api.telegram.org/bot/METHOD_NAME (Reference: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api)

How do I check the history of requests to the API?

For example, if I made a request of form:
HTTP POST https://api.telegram.org/bot/?confirmationToken={confirmationToken}
How do I see this request to the API?

Comment: You tagged `python-telegram-bot`, but you make no indication that you actually use it. In particular, PTB doesn't really allow users to make custom requests to the bot api. Probably the question has already been resolved [here](https://t.me/pythontelegrambotgroup/577929)?